# Preventing and excluding certain attributes from being indexed in Elasticsearch using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, opensearch

I am trying to index a particular model using Ruby on Rails and Elasticsearch but even if I use `index: false` the `email` still shows up on the index? I do not want the email to be indexed, what else can I do to prevent the email attribute from being indexed?

```
mappings dynamic: false do
  indexes :author, type: 'text'
  indexes :title, type: 'text'
  indexes :email, index: false
end
```

I then produce the index and import records using:

`Book.__elasticsearch__.create_index!`

followed by `Book.import force: true`

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *"still shows up on the index"*? This field will still show up on the mapping with `"index": false` meaning this field will still be stored but will not be indexed or searchable. It seems you might be able to use `enabled: false` to avoid the storage as well (although I am not that familiar with elastic search) [index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/explicit-mapping.html#add-field-mapping); [enabled](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/enabled.html)

Comment: Exactly, for security concerns I would like for it to not even be stored. I can still see it when I look at the index manually using something like Elasticvue. That is what I mean.

Comment: Maybe `enabled` is what you are looking for then (at least looking at the docs).  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: It looks like maybe setting the source as synthetic is the only way of preventing a field to be saved within the source, but it is not recommended to set the source as synthetic.  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html#synthetic-source